# Java - Post to Twitter

Tags: java, twitter

I've written a simple web application, which I want to be able to post tweets.

I *have* seen some java libraries for working with Twitter, but they all seem like too much of work for something that is seemingly simple. Is it possible that I am missing something?

Is there any simple way to post a tweet in twitter from a web-app in java with only a few lines of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By trying to resolve the compilation problems in jzd's reply, here's what i came up with:

```
    public static void sendToTwitter(String tweet) {
        ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
          .setOAuthConsumerKey("---")
          .setOAuthConsumerSecret("---")
          .setOAuthAccessToken("---")
          .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("---");

        TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
        Twitter t = tf.getInstance();

        try {
        t.updateStatus(tweet);
        } catch (TwitterException te) {
            te.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And it works just as i wanted it to. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Well using Twitter4J it is fairly easy:

```
TwitterFactory.getInstance(username,password).updateStatus("This goes to Twitter");
```

Comment: Doesn't twitter only allow oauth these days? I would imagine you can't just pass in the password. (Just a hunch, I've never looked at Twitter4J).

Comment: I'm not going to downvote this, but if someone else can confirm this, I would. A few months ago I was messing around with the twitter api for python and the part that was most annoying was that you needed to use oauth to make it work.

Comment: Tested this myself just now, and it failed (authorization exception, I think).  It appears the library does work, but not in one line: https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/tweets/UpdateStatus.java

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but it doesn't work. It doesn't even compile with Twitter4J 2.1.10, which i think is the latest version. First, getInstance is not a static method (any more?), and update is undefined for type Twitter.

Comment: Sorry, should be updateStatus instead of update.  The getInstance takes a password, API: http://twitter4j.org/en/javadoc/twitter4j/TwitterFactory.html#getInstance(java.lang.String, java.lang.String).   oauth is not the only option, Twitter also allows xAuth which is simpler which is what the asker was looking for.  (http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2010/03/using-xauth-an-alternate-oauth-from-twitter/)